# Regular Expression with exceptions

Tags: html, regex

I am looking for a regular expression, that would replace all elements with a non-breaking space EXCEPT: letters, numbers, a dot '.', a question mark '?' and a non breaking space' '.

So for example the string `'hello@world!.'` would become `'hello world .'`.
Can somebody please explain to me how i would do that, since i have very little knowledge of how regular expressions work?

Thank you!

Comment: What programming language? The regex is only the pattern, replacing depends on the language.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged the question html, I guess you need a javascript to do the replacement? If so, this should work:

```
result = subject.replace(/[^\w\d.? ]/g, " ");
```

`[]` means "any of the following characters, but when a `^` is the first character, the selection is negated. `\w` means "word characters", and `\d` means "digits", so translated to English, this pattern would read something like:

Every character that is not a word character, digit, dot, question mark or non breaking space.

The `g` after the pattern means that the pattern is global, and should replace all matches, not just the first one.

Comment: `\d` is already a part of `\w`, but so is the underscore, that OP seems to want to replace. This also won't handle unicode letters/digits as letters/digits.

Comment: `result = subject.replace(/[^\w.? ] |_/g, " ");`

Answer (score 1):

> letters, numbers, a dot '.', a question mark '?' and a non breaking space' '.

This gives the regex: `(&nbsp;|[a-zA-Z0-9.?]+)`

But you want to negate this one, so, you have to use: `(?!&nbsp;)[^a-zA-Z0-9.?]+`

Where:

```
(!&nbsp;)       : is a negative lookahead, that  makes sure we have not &nbsp;
[^a-zA-Z0-9.?]+ : is a character class that matches 1 or more character that are not in the class.
```

```js
var str = 'hello&nbsp;@ world!.';
str = str.replace(/(?!&nbsp;)[^a-zA-Z0-9.?]+/g, "&nbsp;");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a text editor, you can do it like so:

Regex to Find:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9.? ]
```

Replace with: single space .

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PzbadC/1

`[^a-zA-Z0-9.? ]` - Negated character class, Matches anything other than characters from `a to z`, `A to Z`, `0 to 9`, `.`, `?`, and space .